# Animation Between activities Android c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, animation, android-activity, xamarin, between

I am doing this to do simple animation between my activities:

```
<translate

    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"

    android:fromXDelta="0"

    android:fromYDelta="0"

    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"

    android:toXDelta="-100%"

    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

And this to call it:

```
   StartActivity (typeof(detalheVinho));
   OverridePendingTransition (Resource.Animator.animRight, Resource.Animator.animRight2);
```

But i need to animate like it was being read like a book i need to make the activities roll like pages in a book and not just sliding. 
I serched the entire google for libraries or a way so does anyone knows a way?

Answer (score 0):

I notice xamarin does have the viewflipper in layout toolbox. I will try attempt this myself and edit my post if i manage. Link below seems like a good place to start.

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html